# Cybersource Return Security Data : No WS-Security Header

Tags: web-services, security

I had some problem with my cybersource test security key..
this is my web.config/app.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ITransactionProcessor">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="ITransactionProcessor1" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceBilling" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://wcf.tw.gamagic.com/BillingPlus/ServiceBilling.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceBilling"
        contract="BillingWcf.IServiceBilling" name="BasicHttpBinding_IServiceBilling" />
      <endpoint address="https://ics2wstest.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ITransactionProcessor"
        contract="cyberSourceWcf.ITransactionProcessor" name="portXML" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And I use the most updated version of test web service they provided

> https://ics2ws.ic3.com/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor/CyberSourceTransaction_1.109.wsdl

and When I tried the enrollAuthService, the system always return this error
**Security Data : No WS-Security Header**

Do you guys have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

It was fixed for me when I changed security mode from Transport to TransportWithMessageCredential.